# Known Good SQL Logins Failing (Error 18456) Accompanied by "Unable to Reuse a Session" (Error 18056)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am losing my patience with this problem. I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 with all updates.

It is very intermittent. Every now and again this SQL server instance will report the **error:** Login failed for user 'XX'. Reason: Failed to open the database configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection.

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 46.

I know this is a good login, it works all of the other times, and no one changes the credentials.

The above error is immediately followed by this error:

> The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 150, which had been
>   reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may
>   have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs
>   for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 46.

When this occurs a few minutes later this is reported also:

Message

All schedulers on Node 0 appear deadlocked due to a large number of worker threads waiting on ASYNC_NETWORK_IO. Process Utilization 0%.

The above message just keeps repeating until I restart the server.

From researching this issue I've increased the maximum worker threads (currently at 1100). The server has 72G memory and 4 vCPUs, running Windows Server 2008 R2.

i don't encounter this issue at all on my other database servers that run the same environment. Just this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm running out of options.

Comment: did you check this : https://serverfault.com/questions/49631/problems-with-sql-server-2008-the-client-was-unable-to-reuse-a-session-with-s

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks I just posted it there.